# How can I only send leaflet requests on mouse up?

Tags: leaflet

Currently when the map is dragged a few hundred API requests are sent due to many layers.

I would like the requests to only be sent when the map comes to a stop.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help on the GIS network I found that

`updateWhenIdle: true` in the original leaflet options.

will do what I wished.